# Reducing viewport framerate

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, 3d-view, interface

When I am in viewport → render mode, how can I reduce the re-render frequency of the viewport in Cycles engine mode?

So instead of it starting to render again when I slide any attribute in the material nodes, it would wait 250 milliseconds or more between each render on the right

Why? My computer is slow at rendering (weak CPU, no GPU) and I don't want to change all viewport/final render subdivisions, and number of samples each time I preview

[image: blender]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that is an option, but here are some general tips.

In *Rendered View*, there's a button in the top right to pause rendering.

[image]

In *Render Properties* there's a *Simplify* section you can use to cut down several of the most taxing effects without having to make any changes to the objects in the scene.

[image]

If the problem is not the scene geometry, but rather the amount of time it takes to run individual samples, then I suggest a render region with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.  You could also use *Local View* with <kbd>/</kbd> to focus on your selection.

Comment: "in Rendered View, there's a button in the top right to pause rendering": there is?! Where in the right half of my screenshot is it?

Comment: Good tip on the <kbd>/</kbd> with local view. I was using hide/unhide (<kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>Alt+h</kbd>) before which was a hassle, so I'vejust learnt to deal with the inconvenience. Adding <kbd>/</kbd> to my arsenal now :)

Comment: Either that screenshot is in eevee, or the viewport is too narrow to display all the top bar options at once.  You can use scrollwheel up/down to scroll through the top bar.  That wouldn't make much sense though, there appears to be room

Comment: The OP screenshot definitely shows eevee viewport, hence no pause button :)

Comment: I learned it from watching you